# Do something every ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to get current iteration number using track by. I have some array which is one elemented and has only one element at index=2.
If i dont use track by i get error. How to get current iteration?

```
<div ng-repeat="tableData in tables track by $index">{{current_iteration}}</div>
```

Comment: With the `$index` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing :

```
<div ng-repeat="tableData in tables track by $index">

    {{ $index }}

</div>
```

Will result in:

```
0
1
2
4
5
.....
```